# How can I replace age binning feature into numerical data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have created `agebin` column from `age` columns. I have range of `ages` but how can I convert them into `agebin` numerical data type because I want to check whether `agebin` is important feature or not.

I tried following code for age binning:

```
    traindata = data.assign(age_bins =  pd.cut(data.age, 4, retbins=False, include_lowest=True))

    data['agebin'] = traindata['age_bins']

data['agebin'].unique()

[[16.954, 28.5], (28.5, 40], (40, 51.5], (51.5, 63]]
Categories (4, object): [[16.954, 28.5] < (28.5, 40] < (40, 51.5] < (51.5, 63]]
```

What I tried :

```
data['enc_agebin'] = data.agebin.map({[16.954, 28.5]:1,(28.5, 40]:2,(40, 51.5]:3,(51.5, 63]:4})
```

I tried to map each range and convert it to numerical but I am getting syntax error. Please suggest some good technique for converting `agebin` which is categorical to numerical data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need parameter `labels` in [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'age':[10,20,40,50,44,56,12,34,56]})

data['agebin'] = pd.cut(data.age,bins=4,labels=range(1, 5), retbins=False,include_lowest=True)
print (data)
   age agebin
0   10      1
1   20      1
2   40      3
3   50      4
4   44      3
5   56      4
6   12      1
7   34      3
8   56      4
```

Or use `labels=False`, then first bin is `0` and last `3` (like `range(4)`):

```
data['agebin'] = pd.cut(data.age, bins=4, labels=False, retbins=False, include_lowest=True)
print (data)
   age  agebin
0   10       0
1   20       0
2   40       2
3   50       3
4   44       2
5   56       3
6   12       0
7   34       2
8   56       3
```

Comment: Ok so using labels parameter we can convert that age range into single numerical value is it correct ? I want to ask in label range i.e (1,5) is 5 included ?

Comment: no, there is value `bins=4`, so is possible create only `[1,2,3,4]`,

Comment: It is possible check by `print (list(range(1, 5)))`

Comment: I am creating age bins as a new feature i.e I am doing feature engg but I want to ask how can I decide optimal bin size ?

Comment: @stonerock - Hard question for me, because more statistics like coding question. I think better is ask it in [stats.stackexchange.com](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)